# Is there a way to mock snowflake-connector-python module and mock query that will use the mocked cursor and execute the query?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, python-mock

I have a class that generates snowflake connection using credentials and execute a query using the generated cursor.

Now I want to write unit tests that would mock that connection and run query.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, It is possible. You may need to patch 
@patch('snowflake.connector.connect')